# fill section in config file

Tags: c#, app-config

I am new to C # after spending 80 hours learning this language, it is time for me to take the step above; the practice !

I am therefore doing a project that will allow me to test different aspects of C # to help me learn and improve my knowledge.

So I attack from the beginning, the app.config.

I know how to add keys in the default appsetting tags as well as the Sql server connection information via connectionstrings tag with encrypt password (I struggled on this point ^^).

So I still have to see the sections to store / customize information in the app.config file.

I found a pretty good and simple script:

```
 class Config
{
    public class MyConfigSection : ConfigurationSection
    {

        [ConfigurationProperty("STUFF", IsRequired = true, IsDefaultCollection = true)]
        public MyConfigInstanceCollection Instances
        {
            get { return (MyConfigInstanceCollection)this["STUFF"]; }
            set { this["STUFF"] = value; }
        }
    }
    public class MyConfigInstanceCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new MyConfigInstanceElement();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            //set to whatever Element Property you want to use for a key
            return ((MyConfigInstanceElement)element).Name;
        }
    }

    public class MyConfigInstanceElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        //Make sure to set IsKey=true for property exposed as the GetElementKey above
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string)base["name"]; }
            set { base["name"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("code", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Code
        {
            get { return (string)base["code"]; }
            set { base["code"] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to retrieve the information once filled in BUT and that's where it gets stuck, I don't know how to "fill in" the information ...

I wish with the code above to :

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="STUFF" 
             type="My.MyConfigSection, My.Assembly" />
</configSections>
<STUFF>
    <add name="Arme" code="22"/>
    <add name="Armure" code="12"/>
    <add name="Gants" code="45"/>
</STUFF>
```

I'm missing that part of how to increment it.
I tried to play by creating an instance of MyConfigSection but I can't.

I think this is a dumb question on my part, but I can't seem to find an answer on the net other than how to retrieve this information once it's filled out.

Comment: If you're just learning c#, I'd personally advise you to find something else. The entire `System.Configuration` API is pretty much deprecated since .NET Core came out

Comment: Are you trying to change the config file in code? I don't think you mean the word increment here...

Comment: @Lee Taloy : Yes I want to change the config file in code ! :) sorry for my langage.

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto : system configuration is obselete? I am trying to learn it because I want to work in a company in C # for a change of career. I normally develop on another language, but this one is less sought after.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/878910/Change-config-File-at-Runtime-Csharp-Code

Comment: System.Configuration is from the .NET world, which pretty much died. .NET Core introduced the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.* packages

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback, I'll take a look at this :)